# Coverting Str into Int and Float, respectively

Tags: python, string, list, integer

Im a beginner in python so forgive me if the answer is comical :)

I'm trying to write some code that coverts str into int and floats. I will give an example below:

if we are given this:

```
data = [['ab2'], ['-123'], ['BIKES', '3.2'], ['3.0', '+4', '-5.0']]
```

we need to return this:

```
data = [['ab2'], [-123], ['BIKES', 3.2], [3, 4, -5]]
```

I have tried in several ways to do this like so:

```
# first attempt
for sublist in data:
        for value in range(0, len(sublist)): 
            if "." in sublist[value]:
                sublist[value] = float(sublist[value])
            elif sublist[value].isnumeric():
                sublist[value] = int(sublist[value])
# second attempt
for sublist in data:
    for value in sublist:
        if value.isnumeric():
            if int(value) == float(value):
                value = int(value)
            else:
                value = float(value)
```

I keep coming back to the same few problems though:

1. the isnumeric or isdigit doesn't accept "-", "+" or "." in the answer, so if
   i have "-123.4" thats not a number
2. Numbers like 3.0 or 4.0, need to be converted into integers and not floats
3. I need a way to mutate the original list and basically "replace' the old numbers, with new

I know you can use try/except blocks but i haven't studied those and I don't understand them, so if anyone could give me some guidance on what to do, or how to alter my code, it would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: Is this an assignment? Are you not allowed to use try except?

Comment: @Goion Its a project of sorts and we are "limited" to what we have learned, since its being marked. if I use try/expect and I don't even know what it does, then not only am I plagiarizing, I also don't know what it does 

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to use a try-except block. After all, it's easier to ask forgiveness than permission. With a try-except, as soon as an error is encountered in the `try` block, control moves to the `except` block.

In the example below, if `float(value)` fails, a `ValueError` is raised. This error means the `except ValueError:`  block will be executed. Since we just want to ignore the error, we `pass` in the `except` block.

If no error is raised, execution continues on to the next statement (`if float_value...`) and the `except` block is skipped.

```
for sublist in data:
    for index in range(len(sublist)): 
        value = sublist[index]
        
        try:
            float_value = float(value)             # Convert to float
            if float_value.is_integer():           # If successful, check if it's an integer
                sublist[index] = int(float_value)  # If integer, convert to integer and save the integer value
            else:
                sublist[index] = float_value       # If not, save the float
            continue                               # Skip the rest of the loop
        except ValueError:                         # Catch ValueError if float() fails
            pass                                   # Do nothing if error
```

Which gives:

```
data = [['ab2'], [-123], ['BIKES', 3.2], [3, 4, -5]]
```

If you have large integers, you can try to convert it to an `int` *before* you convert it to a `float`, because as Kelly mentioned in their comment, floats lose precision for large ints:

```
    for index in range(len(sublist)):
        value = sublist[index]
        try:
            int_value = int(value)      # Convert to int
            sublist[index] = int_value  # If successful, save
            continue                    # Skip the rest of the loop
        except ValueError:              # Catch the ValueError if int() fails
            pass  

        # And then the try block for floats
```

Comment: If it is an assignemt, then it is highly likely try except isn't allowed.

Comment: I'd still try int first, otherwise for large ints you lose precision.

Answer (score 1):

Using a nested `try`/`except`:

```
def to_num(s):
    # remove trailing ".0"
    x = s.rstrip('0').rstrip('.') if '.' in s else s
    try: # attempt int conversion
        return int(x)
    except ValueError:
        try: # attempt float conversion
            return float(x)
        except ValueError:
            return s   # if all failed return input

[[to_num(x) for x in l] for l in data]
```

Output:

```
[['ab2'], [-123], ['BIKES', 3.2], [3, 4, -5]]
```

Comment: This will screw up the value "1000".

Comment: Your right Tim! I fixed it (not the nicest I admit)

Answer (score 1):

This uses a regex to find valid numbers.  Like most such filters, this creates a new list with the desired values instead of writing in place.

```
import re

nums = r"[+-]?[\d.]+"

data = [['ab2'], ['-123'], ['BIKES', '3.2'], ['3.0', '+4', '-5.0']]

newlist = []
for sublist in data:
    newsub = []
    for value in sublist:
        if re.match( nums, value ):
            if '.' not in value:
                newsub.append( int(value) )
            else:
                value = value.rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
                if '.' not in value:
                    newsub.append( int(value) )
                else:
                    newsub.append( float(value) )
        else:
            newsub.append( value )
    newlist.append( newsub )

print(newlist)
```

Comment: It seems like this might not work with ‘malformed floats’ like 1.1.1.1, which, if present, should probably be kept a string rather than giving an exception, right?

Comment: True, but the OP hasn't provided much of a spec.  ;)   `value.count('.')` might be the most expedient way to handle that.  The regex gets a little complicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Assuming data only contains list and in the list elements can also be list

data = [['ab2'], ['-123'], ['BIKES', '3.2'], ['3.0', '+4', '-5.0']]


def checkPureInt(n):
    n_str = str(n)
    if n_str[-1] == '0' and n_str[-2] == ".":
        return True
    else:
        return False


for i in range(len(data)):
    if type(data[i]) == list:

        for j in range(len(data[i])):
            try:
                data[i][j] = float(data[i][j])
                if checkPureInt(data[i][j]):
                    data[i][j] = int(data[i][j])
            except:
                pass

print(data)
```

Comment: 1. Not a good idea to have a bare silent `except`, since it will catch all errors (that come from possible bugs) and even some keyboard interrupts. 2. `isinstance(data[i], list)` is better than `type(data[i]) == list` 3. Your `checkPureInt()` fails on e.g. `1.00`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi we are not doing anything if str caught. Yes we can also use isinstance, but what problem if we are using type(data[i]) == list? Thanks :)

Comment: `isinstance` works with inheritance. `type() == ` doesn't.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi 3. The function checkPureInt taking int or float in the parameter. I think it is fine. As the problem we need only to check the element is list or not , that's why just using type, list is inbuilt in python so I thought its fine with this question. What you think ?

Comment: Okay, I didn't realize that `checkPureInt()` takes a float. fyi, you can also use `float.is_integer()`. As for the `type` point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/what-are-the-differences-between-type-and-isinstance

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Great!, Thanks for sharing this useful information :)

Answer (score -1):

```
import math
def is_number(string):
    try:
        float(string)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
data=[['ab2'], ['-123'], ['BIKES', '3.2'], ['3.0', '+4', '-5.0']]
for i in range(len(data)):
    for j in range(len(data[i])):
        value=data[i][j]
        if is_number(value):
            if int(float(value)) == float(value):
                data[i][j] = int(float(value))
                #print(value)
            else:
                data[i][j] = float(value)
                #print(value)
print(data)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).